# In DDD and CQRS, for Read queries, what is a strategy that allows for interfaces and easy testing?

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I'm using PHP/MySQL...

I'm using interfaces for repositories on my Domain "command" side. This is going well. But I'm stuck on what to do on the "queries" (read) side. Do I make queries each as separate methods grouped in classes by some common similarity I find? Or do I make each query its own class? How should I go about using interfaces to make testing (and easier replacement later)?

Some places I've researched:

- [A github php example](https://github.com/malocher/zf2-cqrs-sample/blob/master/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/TodoController.php)
- [An attempt to find the best decoupled approach to the read-side queries.](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) Examples use C# unfortunately and make it a bit more challenging to grasp.

These solutions are convoluted?

Answer (score 1):

We currently use the approach from the second c# link for one of our projects.  If you want to use a query facade of some kind, then that's the best one I've come across.  What I like most about it is that you create query objects and query handlers, and then a generic query processor does the work of passing the object to the correct handler.

Overall it works well, however it still feels like I'm working harder than I need to.  I'm not really sure what this query abstraction is giving me, other than having more to maintain.  Testability is often the response to that question, but I for one do not unit test queries.  Unit testing in my opinion is best left for code that can potentially break/affect other code.  Can a query really break anything that wouldn't be immediately apparent during regular testing?  It either works or it doesn't.

If you do have a compelling reason to use a facade, then I recommend grouping the queries that are related into an interface.  Such as "IBillingQueries" and "ICustomerQueries".